# rails - jQuery undefined on load and after works as expected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Rails (using  Rails 5.1.7 on ruby 2.5.3-p105), having a few problems putting a template to work on my landing page.
I'm using `bootstrap 4` and `jQuery 3`.

(Template is this one https://startbootstrap.com/themes/agency/)

[image: Error]

It seems that jQuery is loaded after all the other scripts are loaded, somehow.

I tried to put `jquery` to load before `bootstrap` with no avail. Tried changing orders on turbo_links too.

`assets/javascripts/application.js` is as follows

```
//base
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//
//template
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//
//vendors
//= require jquery-easing/jquery.easing
//
//assets
//= require template/agency
//= require template/contact_me
//= require template/jqBootstrapValidation
```

Do I need to put a javascript_include_tag in `application.html.erb` for `jQuery` and `bootstrap`? Or just the gems will suffice? Could this be the cause?

I was hoping to have the template work exactly as he does standalone.
Can someone shed some light?

Thank you so much!

Edit: the line that throws the error is

```
 // Collapse Navbar
  var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    }
  };
  // Collapse now if page is not at top
  navbarCollapse();
  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);
```

But it shouldn't matter because the point is that jQuery is not loading

Comment: You have to show the code with the line that throws the error. Usually it's something related to not using jquery's `ready` event and turbolinks' `turbolinks:load` event before using jquery's methods. Also, don't mix jquery_ujs and rails-ujs, they do both roughly the same thing but rails-ujs is the official built on rails' core.

Comment: Hi arieljuod! I've updated the question with the code that throws the error, but it shouldn't matter because the error is jQuery not loading. Thanks for the tips, I'll try them out and update.

Comment: Where's that `navbarCollapse` function being called? The problem is not jquery not loading, the problem is that the function runs before jQuery loads (but jquery does load). You should wrap the code that executes that funcion in a callback to jquery's `ready` event https://api.jquery.com/ready/. Also note that you are using turbolinks too, it has it's own event for page load (`document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e){....})`) which is triggered by turbolinks. You may need to nest both callbacks to be sure everything is ready.

Comment: Hi ariel! The function is called right below it. I updated the question with where the function is called. I had better luck with turbolinks though, it finally worked! Add your comment as answer so I can accept it as answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the code that executes that funcion in a callback to jquery's `ready` event https://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Also note that you are using turbolinks too, it has it's own event for page load (`document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e){....})`) which is triggered by turbolinks.

You may need to nest both callbacks to be sure everything is ready.

Something like:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(e) {
  //code that should be run on each page load

  $(document).on('ready', function() { // you can use the shortcut $(function() {
    //code that should be run on each page load after jquery was initialized
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

I've encounter same problem before with jquery gem. Now for all my webapps i will use jquery cdn instead of gem and put after  tag.

Below are codes from my webapps sample.

```html
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js' , 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Aizuddin! Turns out it was something with turbolinks.